# Deadlock in MCS lock implementation

Tags: multithreading, locking, x86-64, atomic, inline-assembly

```
Hardware:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

```
  atomics.hpp

  1 #ifndef ATOMIC_UTILS_H
  2 #define ATOMIC_UTILS_H
  3
  4 #include
  5
  6 #define BARRIER() __asm__ volatile ( "": : :"memory" )
  7
  8 #define CPU_RELAX() __asm__ volatile( "pause\n\t": : :"memory" )
  9
 10 #define STORE_FENCE() __asm__ volatile("mfence" ::: "memory");
 11
 12 class AtomicUtils
 13 {
 14     public:
 15
 16     /**
 17      * check if the value at addr is equal to oldval, if so replace it with newva    l
 18      * and return the oldval
 19      */
 20     inline static size_t compareAndExchange( volatile size_t* addr, size_t oldval    , size_t newval )
 21     {
 22       size_t ret;
 23       __asm__ volatile( "lock cmpxchgq %2, %1\n\t"
 24                     :"=a"(ret), "+m"(*addr)
 25                     : "r"(newval), "0"(oldval)
 26                     : "memory" );
 27       return ret;
 28     }
 29
 30     /**
 31      * Atomically stores x into addr and returns the previous
 32      * stored in addr
 33      */
 34   inline static size_t loadAndStore( size_t x, volatile size_t* addr )
 36     {
 37       size_t ret;
 38       __asm__ volatile( "lock xchgq %1, %0\n\t"
 39                         : "+m"(*addr), "=r"(ret)
 40                         : "1"(x) );
 41       return ret;
 42     }
 43
 44 };
 45
 46 #endif
```

```
  mcs.hpp

  1 #ifndef MCS_LOCK_H
  2 #define MCS_LOCK_H
  3
  4 #include "atomics.hpp"
  5 #include 
  6
  7 class MCSLock
  8 {
  9     struct mcs_lock_t
 10     {
 11         mcs_lock_t():next(0), locked(false){}
 12         struct mcs_lock_t* next;
 13         bool locked;
 14     };
 15
 16     public:
 17     typedef struct mcs_lock_t mcs_lock;
 18
 19     private:
 20     mcs_lock** tail;
 21     static boost::thread_specific_ptr tls_node;
 22
 23     public:
 24     MCSLock( mcs_lock** lock_tail ):tail( lock_tail )
 25     {
 26       if( tls_node.get() == 0 )
 27           tls_node.reset( new mcs_lock() );
 28     }
 29
 30     void lock()
 31     {
 32       mcs_lock* thread_node = tls_node.get();
 33       thread_node->next = 0;
 34       thread_node->locked = true;
 35
 36       volatile mcs_lock* pred = reinterpret_cast(
 37                            AtomicUtils::loadAndStore(
 38                                reinterpret_cast( thread_node ),
 39                                reinterpret_cast( tail )
 40                            )
 41                        );
 42       if( pred != 0 )
 43       {
 44         pred->next = *tail;
 45
 46         STORE_FENCE();
 47         //BARRIER(); // Required to prevent re ordering between prev->next = tail     and thread_node->locked. ( WR harzard )
 48
 49         // Spin on a local variable. Someone unlock me plz !!
 50         while( thread_node->locked )
 51             CPU_RELAX();
 52
 53       }
 54     }
 55
 56     void unlock()
 57     {
 58         mcs_lock* thread_node = tls_node.get();
 59         if( thread_node->next == 0 )
 60         {
 61             // If false, then we a new thread has request for lock. Now release t    he lock for the new thread
 62             if(
 63                     AtomicUtils::compareAndExchange(
 64                         reinterpret_cast( tail ),
 65                         reinterpret_cast( thread_node ),
 66                         0
 67                     )  == reinterpret_cast( thread_node ) 68             )
 69             {
 70                 return;
 71             }
 72
 73             while( thread_node->next == 0 )
 74                 CPU_RELAX();
 75         }
 76
 77         thread_node->next->locked = false;
 78     }
 79 };
 80
 81 boost::thread_specific_ptr MCSLock::tls_node;
 82 #endif
```

```
mcs_test.cpp

  1 #include "mcs.hpp"
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <pthread.h>
  4 #include <vector>
  5 #define NUM_THREADS 16
  6 #define NUM_ITERATIONS 100
  7
  8 std::vector<int> elements;
  9 MCSLock::mcs_lock *tail = 0;
 10
 11 void* thread_run( void* data )
 12 {
 13   MCSLock lock( &tail );
 14   for( int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i )
 15   {
 16       lock.lock();
 17       elements.push_back( i );
 18       lock.unlock();
 19   }
 20
 21   return 0;
 22 }
 23
 24 int main()
 25 {
 26     pthread_t threads[ NUM_THREADS ];
 27     elements.reserve( NUM_THREADS * NUM_ITERATIONS );
 28
 29     {
 30         for( int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i )
 31             pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, thread_run, NULL );
 32
 33         for( int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i )
 34             pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
 35
 36         std::cout <<"\nExiting main thread: " << std::endl;
 37     }
 38 }
```

The above code is compiled using clang

Problem:

I see that 1 or 2 threads are stuck in lock() in line 50. Except the main threads, the threads which are stuck in lock() there are no other threads alive. This means that when the other threads invoke unlock() they somehow don't set the locked = false for other variables and exit.

Any pointers on debugging this please ?

Stuck on this for many hours and no clues.

Comment: Just FYI, rolling your own locks with inline asm is usually pointless.  I could see the benefit of writing your own lockless queue, but using library locks around a plain queue would make more sense.  Even for a lockless queue, use C++11 `std::atomic` instead of hand-rolling your own primitives on top of volatile objects.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I think it is worth putting this in context. This was asked 5-6 years ago. Most of the **stable** versions of distros didn't use GCC that supported C++11's atomic primitives. At one time rolling your own was what you had to do.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I saw the date on the question, 3 years after C++11.  Yeah fair point that std::atomic was relatively new at that point, but it was definitely the right choice at the time, even if that meant installing an updated toolchain.  More importantly, it's definitely the right choice *now* for any current/future readers of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't clang have builtins for these inline-asm blocks (like gcc's __sync_val_compare_and_swap)?  Why re-invent the wheel?

Second, I'd really think about adding the memory clobber to loadAndStore.  You need to make sure that any writes the compiler is holding in registers gets flushed to memory before doing the xchgq.  Similarly it will prevent gcc from optimizing memory reads to before the xchgq.  Either would be bad.

Third, I'd examine the asm output for your while loops (thread_node->locked and thread_node->next).  Since these variables are not volatile, gcc may optimize this to only perform the read once.

These may not solve your problem, but that's where I'd start.